# ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CanCan:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't load my application its giving an above error.

The **routes.rb** file is:

```
resources :patients  

resources :clinics

root :to => "home#index"

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

resources :users

get '/email_send_message', to: "application#show_mail_send_message"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like there is an issue in your application controller. You may have a definition for the CanCan gem, but not have it in your current gem list.

If you do have cancan in your gem list then there may be an issue with how it is configured in your applicaiton controller

Comment: yes, thank you for answer.there was comment on line in gem file where i include the cancan gem.because of that only it was showing an error.